# Sql Server - Format Query Result for an Integer datatyped Column of a table as Array

Tags: arrays, json, sql-server, stringify, sql-server-json

When I run the following query, the result looks like the one provided in screenshot below.

```
DECLARE @numArray VARCHAR(50) = '[1,2,45,1,21,45,32,564,48,56,98,87]';

SELECT  value AS Number  FROM OPENJSON(@numArray)
```

[image]

I was curious if it is possible to it the opposite way. I mean, if I have a query like:

```
Select Number from Table_name
```

then it should provide result like: [1,2,45,1,21,45,32,564,48,56,98,87]

I tried using `For JSON`  but it will just return JSON array.(not int array)

Now I know there are other ways to do it and I have done it too. But is there a way to do this using Sql Server JSON functions?

Thank you

**Edit:**
Currently I am doing this using stuff to concat all the rows. But I want to know if there is something like `FOR JSON PATH` to do so.

Comment: Maybe something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/concatenate-many-rows-into-a-single-text-string?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top

Answer (score 1):

This code may helps you,below is sample data

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#SampleData') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #SampleData
;WITH Cte( SapmleData )
AS
(
SELECT 1    UNION ALL
SELECT 2    UNION ALL
SELECT 45   UNION ALL
SELECT 1    UNION ALL
SELECT 21   UNION ALL
SELECT 45   UNION ALL
SELECT 32   UNION ALL
SELECT 564  UNION ALL
SELECT 48   UNION ALL
SELECT 56   UNION ALL
SELECT 98   UNION ALL
SELECT 87   
)
SELECT * INTO #SampleData FROM Cte

SELECT * FROM #SampleData
```

Using stuff() in sql server

```
SELECT '['+STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ','+ CAST(SapmleData AS VARCHAR(10))   FROM #SampleData
FOR XML PATH ('')),1,1,'') +']' AS Expectedcolumn   

SapmleData
----------
1
2
45
1
21
45
32
564
48
56
98
87

Expectedcolumn
----------------
[1,2,21,32,45,48,56,564,87,98]
```

Comment: Thanks. Currently I am doing it the same way like you. But I wanted to know if there is something similar to 'for json auto' of sql server to do it.

Comment: i think your using sql 2016, but i don't know about json object ,just i know tha json was incorporated in 2016

Answer (score 0):

Try using XML. Like this

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
       Val = 1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
       Val = Val+1
       FROM CTE
          WHERE Val < 10
)
SELECT
    List = '['+SUBSTRING(List,1,LEN(List)-1)+']'
    FROM 
    (
       SELECT
         CAST(Val AS VARCHAR(20))+',' as [text()]
       FROM CTE
       FOR XML PATH('')
    )L(List)
```